# Printing Variable and Polygon together in window OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to print a line of text containing a variable and a point together on my canvas in OpenGL. My code is as follows :

```
 void display()
 {
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    char string[50];
    sprintf(string, "Base Rotation: %d", numVertices); 
    renderMyText(-0.4, 0.35, string);
    glPointSize(20);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(characterX, characterY);
    dx = vertices[numVertices-1].x-ox;
    dy = vertices[numVertices-1].y-oy;
    dt = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    characterX = ox + dx / sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) * Velocity * dt;
    characterY = oy + dy / sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) * Velocity * dt;
    printf("%f %f", characterX, characterY); 
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

I'm using a different method that updates the points position when the mouse moves. That code all works fine and the square updated its position and moved perfectly until I added the line of text.

What happens now is once I start the program the square and text appear but once I move the mouse in the window, the square disappears and only the text remains, I would like the two of them to stay in the window. Can anybody see whats wrong?

Comment: Please show us the rest of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem so I feel I should add the solution :

I was going about this problem in an incorrect way, I should have updated my coordinate values in an idle method like so :

```
    void idle()
{
    //dx is last mouse x - last box x
    dx = vertices[numVertices-1].x-ox;
    //dy is last mouse y - last box y
    dy = vertices[numVertices-1].y-oy;
    dt = 50;
    //dt helps to control the chasing charcters speed
    characterX = ox + dx / sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) * Velocity * dt;
    characterY = oy + dy / sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) * Velocity * dt;
    //equations to move the character after the cursor by moving it along the slope of the line between the two points
    ox = characterX;
    oy = characterY;
    //update object x and y for next calculation
    if((numVertices > 5) && characterX >= vertices[numVertices-1].x - 1 && characterX <= vertices[numVertices-1].x + 1 && characterY >= vertices[numVertices-1].y -1 && characterY <= vertices[numVertices-1].y + 1) { 
        endGame = true;
        //vertices over 5, so that we don't accidentially die when we start, this collision detection code works on a threshold of contact of one
        //between the cursor and object on the X and Y
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

And then the glutPostRedisplay calls the display method where I use the coordinates calculate here to change the location of the Point on screen :

```
        void display() { 
            glColor3f(0,255,0); //set the in game text to green
            if(endGame == true) { 
                glColor3f(255,0,0);
                //if the game is over set the text to red
            }
            glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glPointSize(20);
            glBegin(GL_POINTS);
                glVertex2f(characterX, characterY);
            glEnd();
            glFlush();
            glutSwapBuffers();
}
```